# Deploying portlet on liferay with weblogic 10.3

Tags: deployment, portlet, weblogic-10.x, liferay-6

Currently I have set up liferay 6.1 to weblogic server 10.3.5. 
Now I can use liferay portal from weblogic server. 
After that, I am trying to deploy the other sample portlet to liferay on weblogic server.
I would like to know how to deploy that sample portlet?

Another problem is that I want to develop portlet applicatin that use JSF 2.0 for view and EJB 3.0 for business layer. Can I deploy that portlet applicatin  on liferay with weblogic server. Is that possible. If possible, Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that Weblogic only supports hot deploy for the admin server. There are 2 import settings that liferay needs for hot deployment on weblogic. You need a setting for the weblogic dest dir and a liferay home setting that refers to the root folder of the Weblogic domain. The env.DOMAIN_HOME doesn't work in WLS 10.3.6, that's why you need to set the home location with the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Liferay has a "deploy" folder that it monitors for .war files. You just copy your portlet .war file to that folder, and Liferay deploys it. You can change location of that folder by configuring "auto.deploy.dest.dir" setting in portal-ext.properties.

According to [documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/auto-deploy), on WebLogic by default it has this value:
auto.deploy.weblogic.dest.dir=${env.DOMAIN_HOME}/autodeploy

Also [another part of documentation](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Hot+Deploy+Troubleshooting#section-Hot+Deploy+Troubleshooting-The+Container+Upon+Which+Liferay+Is+Running) mentions that on some containers portlets hot deployment may not work or be problematic. But I think this is not about WebLogic.